# React-native Webview onMessage is not working from a React App source running on localhost

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Inside my React app, on the main index.js file, before rendering the entire React app I placed a `window.postMessage('test', '*');` to make sure that this line gets called no matter what and my React App is running without any issues since before the `postMessage` I was able to spawn a log before that and there was no problem loading the React App afterward. Take note that the app is running on localhost at port 800. Now on a separate React-native app, take note of the following snippet:

```
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    console.log("_onMessage", JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data));
    alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
  };
  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webViewRef}
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.1.5:800' }}
      devToolsEnabled={true}
      onMessage={handleMessage}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
    />
  );
```

Knowing the use of localhost does not work, I used my local ip (which I also tried at the browser and worked) and it successfully rendered my React app inside React-native, the problem though is that when I check the logs on my android emulator using `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`, the log *_onMessage* is not there. Where did it possibly go wrong?